# Have one worksheet mimic another worksheet- VBA, Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Below I have code that provides my Summary sheet with cell values from my Main sheet whenever there is a change in a cell on the main sheet.

This worked great, but I ended up needing to sort the main sheet whenever a new line is added so it is in alphabetical order.

When it is sorted nothing changes in the Summary tab because nothing in a cell was actually changed.

Is there a way to get the summary tab to mimic exactly what the main sheet is doing and not just cell changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```